# Gtk scrolledwindow: strange delay required to scroll to top

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

EDIT: Running on python 3.6, linux, gtk 3.22

I wrote a simple app that display the images in a folder and allows to navigate through them using the arrow keys (basically a simple comic viewer; try it with images with height > width). Each image is zoomed in, so to view its bottom part you need to scroll down. When you load the next image, the app should revert the scrollbar to the upper part. My current code does this correctly only if I wait a few second (i.e. the time it takes for the scrollbar to fade away) before pressing the right arrow key to view the next image, otherwise it loads the next image scrolled to the bottom. I can't understand why.

EDIT: Note that the bug only happens if you scroll with the touchpad, not when dragging the scrollbar.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import os
from gi import require_version
require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf

class Comic:
    def __init__(self, filelist):
        self.files = filelist
        self.index = 0

        self.zoom = 0.50

        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.window.props.can_focus = False
        self.window.props.default_width = 1366
        self.window.props.default_height = 768
        self.window.props.startup_id = 'app.comic'
        self.window.props.title = 'comic'

        self.window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.window.connect("key-press-event", self._on_key_press)

        self.scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scrolledwindow.props.visible = True
        self.scrolledwindow.props.can_focus = True
        self.scrolledwindow.props.hexpand = True
        self.scrolledwindow.props.vexpand = True
        self.window.add(self.scrolledwindow)

        self.image = Gtk.Image()
        self.scrolledwindow.add(self.image)
        self._open_image()

    def _on_key_press(self, win, ev):
        key = Gdk.keyval_name(ev.keyval)
        if key in ('Left', 'KP_Left'):
            self.previous_image()
        elif key in ('Right', 'KP_Right'):
            self.next_image()
        elif key == 'q':
            Gtk.main_quit()

    def _on_resize(self):
        scrolled_allocation = self.scrolledwindow.get_allocation()

        w = self.image_width
        h = self.image_height

        if h > scrolled_allocation.height:
            scale = scrolled_allocation.height / h
            w *= scale
            h *= scale

        if w > scrolled_allocation.width:
            scale = scrolled_allocation.width / w
            w *= scale
            h *= scale

        w = int(w)
        h = int(h)

        w = w + w * self.zoom
        h = h + h * self.zoom

        if (w != self.image_width or h != self.image_height) and w > 0 and h > 0:
            pixbuf = self.pixbuf.scale_simple(w, h, GdkPixbuf.InterpType.BILINEAR)
            self.image.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
            self.image_width = pixbuf.get_width()
            self.image_height = pixbuf.get_height()

    def _open_image(self):
        filename = self.files[self.index]

        self.pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf()
        self.pixbuf = self.pixbuf.new_from_file(filename)
        self.image.set_from_pixbuf(self.pixbuf)
        self.image_width = self.pixbuf.get_width()
        self.image_height = self.pixbuf.get_height()

        self._on_resize()
        return True

    def previous_image(self):
        self.index -= 1
        if self.index <= -1:
            self.index = 0
            return True
        self._open_image()

    def next_image(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.files):
            self.index = len(self.files) - 1
            return True
        self._open_image()
        self._scroll_up()

    def _scroll_up(self):
        adj = Gtk.Adjustment()
        adj.set_value(0.0)
        self.scrolledwindow.set_vadjustment(adj)


def main():
    directory = sys.argv[1]
    ext = ('.jpg', '.jpe', '.jpeg', '.png', )
    images = [os.path.join(directory, f) for f in sorted(os.listdir(directory)) if f.lower().endswith(ext)]

    win = Comic(images)
    win.window.show_all()
    Gdk.threads_enter()
    Gtk.main()
    Gdk.threads_leave()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issues here. Maybe you could give some additional info about on which configuration/system you run this?

Comment: For me, some photos work as you wanted, some don't.

Comment: @mondegreendispenser added. Found why you can't reproduce: you need to scroll with the touchpad, not by dragging the scrollbar

Comment: @theGtknerd Yes, if you wait enough it works, if you hurry to the next one it doesn't. (there's also an issue where sometimes the image is loaded but not displayed, but that's for some other time =D )

Comment: also: you need to make sure that both the current image AND the next one will be displayed zoomed, so that you can scroll to bottom